# Orbot Hidden Services

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, orbot

I am trying to set up a hidden service on my android device but i am running into some problems. On the computer i set the hidden service directory and my keys are where they are supposed to be. Using Orbot, i don't have that option. There i a ".Onion hostname" area in the configuration but nothing is populating that field.

Am i missing something? Please let me know your thoughts if you have been able to launch hidden services successfully from Orbot.

I am using kWS as the web server on the device and am getting an 'unable to read hidden service name' message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need to enable hidden service put in the port number then resart orbot once you connected to tor go back to the settings and then there will be a .onion address generated.

Comment: I did all of that.. I just installed a dev orbot and it seems to be working better now. At least the onion name is coming up for me. I'll consider this one closed for now.